# How to fix this issue I am having about MySQL on Mac OS Monterrey?

Tags: mysql, terminal, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect my MySQL Workbench, and I updated my mySQL. I ran "sudo mysql.server status" on terminal, and got this error:

````
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.15/bin/my_print_defaults
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1h/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' (no such file)
 ERROR! MySQL is not running```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
```

Then look at the prompt to install the corresponding version, which may not be S.

Comment: Error: Unknown command: switch

Comment: @Michael install openssl

Comment: that worked but I am still getting the same error

Comment: I got "SUCCESS! MySQL running (54312)", would this mean I need to use 54312 as the port? Thanks!

Comment: ps -ef|grep mysql  Or cat my.cnf